# How to get bool value from PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I am trying to get bool value from PHP MySQL. I want to print this bool value. I get 2 values NULL & BOOL VALUE.
Here is my codes:

```
 Future<String> getTabData() async {
    final postData = {"token": uToken};
    final sendResponse = await http.post(serverURL + "/addpage.php", body: postData);

    if (sendResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userData = jsonDecode(sendResponse.body);
      var resCode = await userData["res"];
      return resCode;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load content');
    }
  } //_getTabData



  String _rCode="";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    if (_rCode == "") {
      getTabData().then((String rxCode) =>
          setState(() {
            _rCode = rxCode;
          }));
    }
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String rCode = _rCode;
    print("RC: $rCode");

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .width,
              height: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: grdMainGradient,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call directly asynchorous in initState().

you should change:

```
    initState(){
     fetchData();
    }

void fetchData() async{
  String value = await getTabData();
 print(value);
}
```

Comment: Will try this codes and update you accordingly. Thank you @Trần Nhật Nam Lê

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this code?

```
var resCode = await userData["res"];
```

If so, you might want to double check that `userData["res"]` actually contains `true` or `false`, not `"true"` or `"false"`, as it may be represented as a string instead of bool; and if you're sure that `userData["res"]` will always contain bool value, change `var resCode` to `bool resCode`.

Comment: As per suggestions, I tried :

`fetchData() async
  {
    bool _rCode = await getTabData();
     return _rCode;
  }`

`addCD()
  {
    bool rx=fetchData();
    return rx;
  }`

Now adding `addCD()` in widget gives me error 

`type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'`